# Delphi: acmstreamconvert error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am using acmStreamConvert to convert voice buffer sent over internet and play it. Everything was working fine but there are some users who became a pain in the ***, the voice buffer sent over the internet are converted this way.

```
Procedure WriteBuffer(Buffer: Pointer; SrcBufferUsed: Cardinal; var DestBuffer: Pointer; var DestBufferUsed: Cardinal);
Var rDestBuffer: Cardinal;
Begin
  Move(Buffer^, FACMConverter.InBuffer^, SrcBufferUsed);
  rDestBuffer:= FACMConverter.Convert(SrcBufferUsed);
  DestBuffer := FACMConverter.OutBuffer;
  DestBufferUsed := rDestBuffer;
End;

Function FACMConverter.Convert(SrcBufferUsed: Cardinal): Cardinal;
Begin
  FillChar(FOutBuffer^, OutputBufferSize, 0);
  FStreamHeader.cbSrcLength := SrcBufferUsed;
  acmStreamConvert(FStreamHandle,FStreamHeader, ACM_STREAMCONVERTF_BLOCKALIGN);
  acmStreamReset(FStreamHandle, 0);
  Result := FStreamHeader.cbDstLengthUsed;
End;
```

In normal scenario it works fine, but some users are editing the packets using packet sniffer and messing with the voice buffer, when that packet is sent over to other users, the application start generating access violation errors and crashes. Is there any way to validate the voice buffer before passing it acmStreamConvert?

P.S: When a normal buffer is passed the usual output size in FStreamHeader.cbDstLengthUsed is somewhere between 7680 and 8340, but when a corrupted buffer is passed the value returned is the value of maximum memory that the converter can use for the stream, the values are known after the acmStreamConvert is called by which point its already too late to do anything.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The code that calls acmStreamConvert fails to check the return value. The return value of acmStreamConvert indicates whether or not the call succeeded, and if it failed, why.

So I suspect that you need to modify the code to check the return value of acmStreamConvert. If that return value is non-zero, do not proceed.

In fact, you make another call to the ACM library in the code in the question, and do not check the return value. I suggest that you audit the code fully for missing error checking. Consult the documentation of each API function you call to see how error checking is to be handled.

Comment: I tried with the return value, but return value is also 0, the only thing that shows that the buffer is corrupted is the cbDestLengthUsed in FStreamHeader

I am using an ACM codec named speexw.acm